# node.js soap attachments files/ cid href

Tags: node.js, soap, soapui, node-soap, xop

i'm using node-soap to consume laposte web service which is suppose to send me a response with a PDF attachment.

But what I get is not a file but a href such as the following

***href: 'cid:c482ea77-cc5b-406f-8596-295470ce8049-100134@cxf.apache.org'***

In the docs, this attachement is describe as a *XOP binary file* :  didn't understand what that mean neither how to handle and open it in node...

**Do you have a hint on how to handle such files/href/cid ?**

Bonus question: why on earth an entreprise like Laposte (main delivery service in France) is still using technology like this with so little documention an crowd appropriation ?

Best <3

Answer (score 0):

`cid` is name of different protocol than http(s) you are using for soap.

For reason why it exists or how it works go to http://www.cid-protocol.org